# CSS: max-width to be flex: 1

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container with `display: flex;`. There are two columns inside, one with fixed width, the other is a resizable panel (like JS fiddle, can be dragged to change width).

I set `flex: 1;` for the resized component to take up all remaining spaces, however, as it's draggable, its width can now increase to over 100% of the screen and there's a horizontal scrollbar in the browser.

So I want to restrict the draggable component's width, to be no more than the entire screen (scrollbar shouldn't come up).

That is, I want something like `max-width: 'flex: 1'`. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you share code please.

Comment: @Hemant It's hard -- the scrollable one is a React component, and js style is applied everywhere

Comment: "I want to restrict the draggable component's width, to be no more than the entire screen " , then why not `max-width: 100vw`

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao `max-width: 100vw or 100%` doesn't work, probably because the draggable component's width keeps changing. `max-width: 800px` works tho.

Comment: Strange, can't really comment until I see the code.

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao I know, sorry:( Styled Components are hard to share. But max width 88 vw works - might because there's also a fixed width column besides. How can I work out vw correctly?

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao Just solved! I changed the first item from fixed width to 10vw, the draggable one to 90vw, and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: A fixed width column? Then just use `calc(100vw - 20em)` or whatever the width of the column is.

Comment: @MrLister Yep, it works, thanks.

Comment: Haha, I have no idea how I even helped, but good for you.

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao You helped by pushing the OP into revealing that they also had a fixed width sidebar ;)